# Django Social Auth access first_name and last_name

Tags: python, django, facebook, authentication

I've been trying to get Facebook login to work for my Django application. I have a custom user, except it seems that upon Facebook authentication, Facebook only passes back the user's username, whereas I would like the username, email, first_name, last_name, and profile picture. The other problem I have is that upon successful authentication, my app simply returns to the original URL with `'#_=_'`.

My biggest issue is I don't know how to receive the proper results I need from the Facebook authentication and the documentation doesn't seem to cover it.

Settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
        'trending.backend.ActiviistUserBackend',
        'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'trending',
    'gunicorn',
    'cloudinary',
    'social_auth',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'fields': 'id,name,email', 
}

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.social_auth_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.associate.associate_by_email',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.associate_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.load_extra_data',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.update_user_details',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.create_user'
)

LOGIN_URL = '/log_in/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/log_in/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'trending.ActiviistUser'


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
```

Log_in.html

```
<div id = 'wrapper'><div id = 'shiftlog'>

<h1>Log In</h1>
<br>
<form action="/log_in/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
</form><br><br>

<a href='/sign_up/' id = 'signup'>Need an Account?</a>
<a href="{%url 'socialauth_begin' 'facebook' %}">Login with Facebook</a>

</div></div>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
# Create your models here.

class ActUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def create_user(self, email, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, email and password.
        """
        print email
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=email, **extra_fields)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class ActiviistUser (AbstractBaseUser):
    firstname = models.CharField(verbose_name="First Name", max_length=30, default="")
    lastname = models.CharField(verbose_name="Last Name", max_length=30, default="")
    username = models.CharField(verbose_name="User Name", max_length=30, default="")
    is_active  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='Email Address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        default=''
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    objects = ActUserManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

Define this setting:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_EXTRA_DATA = ['first_name', 'last_name']
Then you can access those values with:

social = user.social_auth.get(provider='facebook')
userid = social.uid
first_name = social.extra_data['first_name']
last_name = social.extra_data['last_name']
```